# Acquiring Aggregate Total in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

I am working with PostgreSQL in Apache Superset. using the following code:

```
 SELECT district_name AS district_name,
   facility_name AS facility_name,
   encounter_date AS __timestamp,
   SUM(facility_encounters.measles_1) + SUM(facility_encounters.mr_1) AS "Measles + MR 1",
   SUM(facility_encounters.mr_2) + SUM(facility_encounters.measles_2) AS "Measles + MR 2",
   SUM(facility_encounters.bcg_1) AS sum__bcg_1,
   SUM(facility_encounters.rota_1) AS sum__rota_1,
   SUM(facility_encounters.rota_2) AS sum__rota_2,
   SUM(facility_encounters.opv_1) AS sum__opv_1,
   SUM(facility_encounters.opv_2) AS sum__opv_2,
   SUM(facility_encounters.pentavalent_1) AS sum__pentavalent_1,
   SUM(facility_encounters.pentavalent_2) AS sum__pentavalent_2,
   SUM(facility_encounters.pentavalent_3) AS sum__pentavalent_3,
   SUM(facility_encounters.opv_3) AS sum__opv_3,
   SUM(facility_encounters.opv_4) AS sum__opv_4,
   SUM(facility_encounters.pcv_1) AS sum__pcv_1,
   SUM(facility_encounters.pcv_2) AS sum__pcv_2,
   SUM(facility_encounters.pcv_3) AS sum__pcv_3
   FROM facility_encounters
   WHERE encounter_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
   AND encounter_date <= '2018-12-31 00:00:00'
   GROUP BY district_name,
     facility_name,
     encounter_date
   ORDER BY "Measles + MR 1" DESC
   LIMIT 10000;
```

How do I aquire:

a) the count of how many children were immunized at each facility, per antigen in a given period?

b) Immunization coverage per facility per antigen in a given period?

c) Total number of fully immunized children per facility per period?

d) Number of children seen/immunizations given should be broken down to the    specific No. of antigens given per specified period of time per facility.

e) Coverage for under 1s is very important, however it will also be very important to have statistics for under 2 to monitor how many are getting measles 2.  In dashboard context, there’s need to display the fully immunized coverage at age 1. Coverage for under 2s is also preferred.